# forEach is not a function omdb and api express

Tags: javascript, api, express

```
    app.get('/result',(req, res)=>{
    //request("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=harry potter&apikey=thewdb",(error, 
   request("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=harry potter&apikey=thewdb",(error, response,body)=>{
       if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
           var data = JSON.parse(body)
            res.render("results", {data:data})
            //res.send(typeof parseData)
       }else{
            res.send(error)   
       }
   })
});
```

my results.ejs page

```
<% data.forEach(function(movie) {%>
    <li><%=movie.title%></li>
<%}) %>
```

Im getting the error forEach is not a function
im pretty new to api and express
Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, can you please add your code as text rather than an image? (see details [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5648954) as to why this is preferred).

Comment: Are you sure `data` is an array and not something else (eg: an object?)

Comment: I just checked that API, and it does not return an Array

Comment: @NickParsons im sorry pretty new to program and stackoverflow, ill try to edit it

Comment: @Bravo i tried copy pasting it on my browser and it show
// 20201201131629
// http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=harry%20potter&apikey=thewdb

{
  "Title": "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2",
  "Year": "2011",
  "Rated": "PG-13",
 
 "Released": "15 Jul 2011",
  "Runtime": "130 min",
  "Genre": "Adventure, Drama, Fantasy, Mystery",
  "Director": "David Yates",
  "Writer": "Steve Kloves (screenplay), J.K. Rowling (novel)",

Comment: it's fairly simple: the api does not return an Array - therefore you can not use an Array method on the data

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint : http://omdbapi.com/?t=harry%20potter&apikey=thewdb won't return an `JSON collection` that Javascript will translate into an `array of objects`, but it retutns a single `object`.
And you cannot loop through an object using the `Array.prototype.forEach`  method.

Here is the result from the endpoint that you've posted

[image]

Your `loop` will never work on a object

Comment: thanks for your response i tried converting it by using var data = JSON.parse(body)

and if a use the data on my results page it show [object] [object]

Answer (score 0):

```
<% data["Search"].forEach(function(movie){%> 
    <li><%= movie.Title %> </li>
<%}) %>
```

To those who will encounter same problem as mine, this api needed the["search"] in order to make it work.